# How to disable csrf protection for a route with dynamic parameter?

Tags: laravel, routes, csrf

I have a route which has a dynamic parameter at the end of the URL. In this route, I fetch data which is sent from an external API with the post method. As `419 page expired` error occurs when the external API sends post request, I need to disable csrf protection for this route.

Related route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:student']], function (){
    Route::post('Result', 'ExamController@Result')->name('exam.Result');
}
```

My URL example:

`http://localhost.dev/student/Result?Id=N7utfGkwOLebxMWGA5iUC4S23jgRzW`

I tried to add this code in `VerifyCsrfToken` file at `App\Http\Middleware`:

```
protected $except = [
'student/Result/*',
];
```

It doesn't work. But when I try `student/*`, it works perfectly. However, disabling the csrf protection for all  `student` path is not what I want.

I tried also this way by getting reference on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757548/9905979):

```
Route::post('Result', [
      'uses' => 'ExamController@Result',
      'nocsrf' => 'true'
    ])->name('exam.Result');
```

That didn't work either.

How can I disable csrf protection in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo at `App\Http\Middleware`, instead of:

```
protected $except = [
'student/Result/*',
];
```

You need to use:

```
protected $except = [
'student/Result',
];
```

Also, based on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) you can specify the full url that need to be excepted:

```
protected $except = [
'http://localhost.dev/student/Result',
];
```

Be aware, that you don't need to add parameters part (everything after `?` sign, e.g. `?Id=N7utfGkwOLebxMWGA5iUC4S23jgRzW`) of route here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (remove the slash and asterisk):

```
protected $except = [
'student/Result',
];
```